# Python: Replace characters in string at different positions with arguments

Tags: python, string

It's a simple question. I have a generic string and I want to replace an asterisk `*` with arguments provided.

```
'* is the capital of *'
```

If I shall give two arguments `('Berlin','Germany')`, I should get

```
'Berlin is the capital of Germany'
```

It's an easy problem, and I can solve it, but I am looking for one line solution where every positional argument replaces the corresponding `*`. I think, I have seen something of this type `(*) ...(*)`, but can't recollect. Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many ways to do this, a simple one if you have tuples of 2 elements:

```
t = ('Berlin', 'Germany')
'{} is the capital of {}'.format(*t)
```

or

```
'%s is the capital of %s' % t
```

output: `'Berlin is the capital of Germany'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an f-String like this:

```
city = "Berlin"
country = "Germany"
print(f"{city} is the capital of {country}")
```

Basically, you're no longer using arguments and formatting, you're putting the python code directly into the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the '*' with '{}', you can use the `format` method:

```
s = '* is the capital of *'
replacement = ['Berlin', 'Germany']
print(s.replace('*', '{}').format(*replacement))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to avoid replace all together.